# Check if Facebook user exists using Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for a way to check if there is a Facebook user with a particular ID.

I know that there is an Graph API which can return Facebook user's profile picture for given ID, it works like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/#USER_ID_HERE#/picture

and I see that if I enter ID that doesn't exists it returns error, however I'm still very new to JavaScript so I don't really know how to "read" that error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code by using jQuery.

```
var pictureUrl= "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture";
$.ajax({
    url : pictureUrl,
    statusCode: {
        200: function() {
            alert("user exist");
        },
        404: function() {
            alert( "user not exist" );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sometimes this method returns OAuthException. How to find workaround ?

Comment: what if we dont know the user id?